# error in train casacde

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

Hi I am having an error saying "Train dataset for temp stage can not filled. Branch training terminated. Cascade Classifier can't be trained. check the used training parameters" when I am trying to do training. I used 50 positive and 100 negative images. I saw a similar question [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/10872/cascade-training-error-opencv-244-train-dataset/) . My bg.txt file is already in the form mentioned in that solution but still having the error.

my console output was as follows-

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\cv_traincascade
\Debug>cv_traincascade.exe -data test -vec positives.vec -bg infofile.txt -numPos 50 -
numNeg 100 -numStages 20 -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcIdxBufSize 1024 -w 24 -h 24


PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: test
vecFileName: positives.vec
bgFileName: infofile.txt
numPos: 50
numNeg: 100
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] :1024
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] :1024
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 24
sampleHeight: 24
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: BASIC
===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   50 : 50
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters.
```

Can anyone please say what is wrong in my command? any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your Background dataset, otherwise it would move through the Bg Count and start the classifier. Check the file locations are all correct in your background file "infofile.txt"

EDIT: Upload a portion of your bg file.

Comment: there is no problem in the 'infofile.txt' , I am sure because I used same with the older version 'haartraining.exe' and it works fine.